# FFmpeg: Create a Video Slideshow from PNG Images for MS PowerPoint

Tags: video, image-processing, ffmpeg, powerpoint, animated-gif

I am using FFmpeg on Windows 7 to create a video from PNG image sequence for Microsoft PowerPoint.

The best results I have achieved so far, is by using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -start_number 3 -i .\folder\name_%d.png -q:v 0 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p output-video.avi
```

It seems perfect, 50 images of total size 30 MB are converted into ~200 KB video with no loss in the quality. Placing it in PowerPoint also seems right, but there is a slight color shift (yellow appears darker and possibly more orangish). By using some other conversion options, I obtained a video in PowerPoint where the first image of the video (like album cover art) is exactly as the original but the rest of the video plays with the mentioned color shift.

When I play this file in VLC, it's good. Although, if in the settings "Use hardware YUV->RGB conversions" is enabled, colors appear a bit washed out, and white color is a bit gray.

I also tried to convert the images to a GIF file and at first it seems good but outer edges and numbers from the left and top side are blurred, and the background has turned from white to a bit gray color, although, white segments not on the background are white. The output size is 18 MB. I ended up with a way better GIF ~600 KB by converting from the first video file; just it is slightly more dotted, and the background again is grayish.

```
ffmpeg -i output-video.avi output-video.gif
```

Could someone help?

Comment: Try inserting `-vf scale=dst_range=1`

Comment: @Mulvya wow, that definitely helped. But now the contrast is higher in the video.

Comment: Ok, `-vf scale=dst_range=0` and `-color_primaries 1 -color_trc 1 -colorspace 1 -color_range 1`. This will depend on how much PPT obeys the video metadata I'm adding here.

Comment: The same in both cases. Now, it is quite interesting, in PowerPoint, it appears with more contrast than the original images. And now it looks the same in VLC when the conversion option is disabled, but when it is enabled, the video appears as in PowerPoint before!

Comment: @Mulvya, sorry to make confusion, I accidentally included `and` from your last comment. In the later case, I actually get the same as myself previously. The previous comment is true for `-vf scale=dst_range=1`.

Comment: Add `-color_primaries 1 -color_trc 13 -colorspace 0 -color_range 2` **before** `-i`

Comment: I could not find any difference. So far the changes have been dependent only on `-vf scale=dst_range`.